# メソッド呼び出し

Tags: java, kotlin

```
public class BookmarkImport {

    fun improt() {
        println("BookmarkImport:main")
        var uri = "http://api.atnd.org/events/?keyword=android&format=json"
        val asyncJsonLoader = AsyncJsonLoader(object : AsyncJsonLoader.AsyncCallback
    }
```

呼び出し側

```
BookmarkImport()　//これだとダメ
```

BookmarkImportクラスの`improt()`を呼び出すにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

色々試しましたがうまくいきません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

宣言している関数名を打ち間違いしていませんか？（○import, ×improt）

```
public class BookmarkImport() {
    fun import() {
        println("BookmarkImport:main")
        // var uri = "http://..."
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var bi = BookmarkImport()
    bi.import()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
luna:~ % cat test.kt
public class BookmarkImport {
    fun improt() {
        println("BookmarkImport:main")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var bi = BookmarkImport()
    bi.improt()
}
luna:~ % /tmp/kotlin/kotlin-master/dist/kotlinc/bin/kotlinc test.kt
info: PERF: INIT: Compiler initialized in 557 ms
info: PERF: ANALYZE: 1 files (10 lines) in 608 ms
info: PERF: GENERATE: 1 files (10 lines) in 55 ms
luna:~ % /tmp/kotlin/kotlin-master/dist/kotlinc/bin/kotlin TestKt
BookmarkImport:main
luna:~ %
```

うまくいかないコードを、他の人が試せるように、断片的でなくかつ最小限にして質問に掲載すると、回答しやすいと思います。